# How to call rest api with socket io program?

Tags: node.js, http, socket.io, request

I'm trying to call a rest API with socket io program,
I'm very new to the socket programming here, this is my code and I want only server function no client

```
 var app = require('express')();
    var http = require('http').Server(app);
    var io = require('socket.io')(http);


    io.on('connection', function (socket) {
      var options = {
        host: 'www.google.com',
        port: 80,
        path: '/',
        method: 'GET'
      };
      var req = http.request(options, function(res) {
        console.log('STATUS: ' + res.statusCode);
        console.log('HEADERS: ' + JSON.stringify(res.headers));
        res.setEncoding('utf8');
        res.on('data', function (chunk) {
          console.log('BODY: ' + chunk);
        });
      });
      req.end();
    });

    http.listen(3000, function() {
        console.log('listening on *:3000');
     })
```

Comment: you dont need express to run socket.io, and https://nodejs.org/api/http.html can make requsts, rtm

Comment: What exactly is the problem you want help with?